# Upgrade from Qt 5.7 to 5.10 results in slower UI

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I've installed Qt 5.10 alongside 5.7, and when compiling the same project I get a very weird side-effect, my user interface is extremely slow (sometimes takes few seconds for a button push to process).
I've looked at the cpu measurements, it doesn't look like it's working harder. Has anybody encountered such issue? Any directions to solving it / understanding the cause?
Using ubuntu 16.04, with GCC 7.2 for both setups.

**EDIT**

Following an advice in the comments (thanks @n.m), ran with strace, looks like there is something different with the mouse handling, I think. While the 5.7 version finds this file 
`open("/usr/share/icons/default/index.theme", O_RDONLY) = 11`

The 5.10 version is looking for it in another location, and fails. Later, it finds another file for it.
`open("/home/innereye/.icons/DMZ-White/index.theme", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

`open("/usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursors/xterm", O_RDONLY) = 19`

Comment: Run your program under strace and see if there's any syscall it hangs within for unreasonable amount of time.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it, just normal read/write, when I press a button it hangs but still on the read/write functions (I guess that they are screen related, they run when I move the cursor)

Comment: So it's an unusually large amount of calls to read and write, right? Are all or most of them to the same file descriptor?

Comment: Take a look at my edit

Comment: This should't take a whole of one second, and should only be done once per run anyway! The sequence looks perfectly normal (look in user's configs, if not found, look in the system place). If this sequence is done many times for the same theme file, there's a bug in Qt. If not, the reason is elsewhere.

Comment: It runs only once. But still, each press is slow...

Comment: So what do you see in the strace window between the moment you press a button and the moment your application reacts?

Comment: Just read and write to the same file descriptor (I can't find where the fid was opened, I assume it's the screen)

Comment: A profiler is the right tool to dig into this issue.

Comment: @Murphy The usual profilers (callgrind, gprof) are generally not very suitable for this as they only show CPU usage, not wait time.

Comment: You can look at /proc/<pid>/fd to see which file or socket it opens. I too think it's the display. Perhaps your app is running in synchronous mode for some reason.

Comment: @n.m. This assumes that the additional time is spent in the kernel, which is yet to be proven. And there are tools like [OProfile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/about/) which should cover this case.

Comment: @Murphy The additional time is spent *waiting*. The kernel is running other processes or idling, because CPU is not working harder. Which is why I don't think OProfile is going to help either (I don't remember it measuring wait time). But one can always try...

Comment: Checked again, only one of my widgets is slow. It's nothing special, a widget that inherits from QWidget. Not overriding of the paint/resize/any event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've found a solution (more of a workaround).
After looking in to it, figured out that setting a background image was causing the problems.
This is the code I had for it -

```
QPalette palette;
palette.setBrush(this->backgroundRole(), QBrush(QImage("/path/to/img.jpg").scaled(1870, 1020)));
this->setPalette(palette);
```

Now I change my QWidget to a QFrame, and used

```
setStyleSheet("QFrame {background-image: url(/path/to/img.bmp);}");
```

And it works.